# How to calculate the efficiency of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

So I was given this algorithm to compute the efficieny in which I found sorts an array into ascending order.

```
solvethis(T[1..n])
    for i = 1 to n-1 do   //n
       minJ = i           //n-1
       minX = T[i]        //n-1
       for j = i+1 to n do  //sum_{i=1}^{n} t
          if T[j] < minX then ** //sum_{i=1}^{n} t-1
             minJ = j             //sum_{i=1}^{n} t-1
             minX = T[j]         ////sum_{i=1}^{n} t-1
      T[minJ] = T[i]      //n-1
      T[i] = minX         //n-1
```

I also listed the number of times the line of code is run. I need to find the efficiency and how many time the line at ** is calculated. Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Comment: To calculate the efficiency you have to do it, in terms of the worst case possible. One loop will traverse the array at least n times. And it seems, you have two loops so this means your operations will be N * N which is N^2 on a worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way (The way I was taught at least) is to look for a basic operation. That's the operation that most significantly impacts the performance of an algorithm. In your case it looks like `if T[j] < minX then` would be your basic operation as it's performed the most times, where the statements inside of the `if` check are only performed if the condition is true. The fact you have two for loops going from `1` to `n-1` tell me that you're working with quadratic time. You're going to be doing your basic operation at minimum n^2 or n operations n times. This should tell you that your algorithm performs in O(n^2) timing.